# ACRA not sending logcat

Tags: android, acra

**EDIT**

With credit to F43nd1r, the solution is to put LOGCAT in your ReportsCrashes annotation, e.g.

```
@ReportsCrashes (
  mailTo = "log@perinote.com",
  mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
  customReportContent = {ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, 
                         ReportField.STACK_TRACE, 
                         ReportField.LOGCAT},
  resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm trying out ACRA and would like it to capture the stack trace and logcat. At the moment, I have it configured to invoke my email app to send the data. Upon a crash, it is display a toast and is opening the email app with the stack trace in the message body. However, there is no logcat.

As best as I can tell according to the documentation, when I put the READ_LOGS permission in the manifest, it should include the last 200 lines of the logcat in the report.

I'm testing on an Android 7.0 device.

manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.perinote.crashtest"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>

  <application
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

package com.perinote.crashtest;

```
import ...;

@ReportsCrashes (
  mailTo = "log@perinote.com",
  mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
  resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)

public class AppSubclass extends Application
{
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
  {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    ACRA.init (this);
  }
}
```

I don't think any other of my files are relevant, but let me know if you need more info.

Comment: **Nitpick**: READ_LOGS is not used. you have to have the system signature to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Including a full report could be quite difficult due to the data size. Default fields included in email reports are:
>
> - ReportField.USER_COMMENT
> - ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION
> - ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME
> - ReportField.BRAND
> - ReportField.PHONE_MODEL
> - ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA
> - ReportField.STACK_TRACE

Source: [Sending Reports by Mail](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations#sending-reports-by-email)

So, if you want to include logcat, you have to modify the report fields to include ReportField.LOGCAT.

---

Note that starting from ACRA 4.9.3 (Unreleased) you'll be able to send the report as a mail attachment instead of as body, so size shouldn't be a problem anymore.
Until then, including logcat might result in unsendable reports (as they might exceed character limits imposed by mail providers).

---

**The above answer only applies to ACRA 4.x.** In ACRA 5.x the default configuration is the same for all senders and does include logcat.

Comment: My question states that *no* logcat was included in the email - attachment or in body. Do you have an answer for my question? Thanks.

Comment: That's because logcat is not in the default list - you have to include it. Edited answer for clarity.

Comment: Thank you, thank you ! This works. Unfortunately, their documentation says only to include the READ_LOGS permission in the manifest. Even on the page you reference, there is no mention of ReportField.LOGCAT.